# What tools exist to help finding  memory leaks for handles?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks

What tools exist to help finding memory leaks for handles?
I have a file.exe and an inproc-server dll, which is using file.exe. I have about 10 memory leaks of handles evertyime it completes its operation.

Comment: Questions about debugging methodology, without specific examples, are a better fit for programmers.se

Comment: I disagree, but this question is hard to understand, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Very hard to understand. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) is one of the SysInternals tools that you can use to show the handles that a program has allocated.  You have to configure the lower pane view to show handles in order to see them.  It tells you the type of handle, which may help in finding the source of the leak.  It won't tell you an allocation path, but it is still useful when other tools also can't detect the leaks.

I've also used DevPartnerStudio successfully to find a lot of leaks. (http://www.microfocus.com/products/micro-focus-developer/devpartner/index.aspx).  It does have a tendency to report false leaks, so you have to play with the settings to make sure you're getting accurate results.  It is a very good product and I always suggest buying it when doing C++ development on Windows.